# "Whole word" search in a NSString through NSPredicate

Tags: cocoa-touch, core-data, nsstring, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

I would like to search if in the attribute `description` (an `NSString` instance) there is a given word.

I tried with this predicate:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"description CONTAINS[cd] %@", theWord];
```

It works, but it finds also *sub-words*.

For example, given `theWord`:

> Car

it will mach also this `description`:

> A Christmas Carol

Instead, I would like that my predicate will match only `a`, or `christmas`, or `carol`.

(I'm using Core Data and NSFetchRequest.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Something like this?

```
NSString *matchStr = @".*\\bCarol\\b.*";

NSPredicate *pred =[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"description MATCHES %@", matchStr];

NSArray *arr = @[ 
    @"A Christmas Carol",
    @"Sing",
    @"Song"
];

NSArray *filtered = [arr filteredArrayUsingPredicate: pred];
```

The trick is the `\b` metacharacter, which denotes a word boundary in the string. In order to get a backslash "into" the regex pattern string, you have to precede it with another backslash so the compiler understands that there should be a real backslash in the string. Hence the "\\b" in the string.

Also, in order to cover non-English language strings better, you should enable Unicode word boundary detection, by setting the `w` flag option. The match string will look like this:

```
NSString *matchStr = @"(?w).*\\bCarol\\b.*";
```

Comment: If you're going to be putting user input in there (like `theWord`), I'd recommend escaping it. So make `matchStr` something like `[NSString stringWithFormat:@".*\\b%@\\b.*", [NSRegularExpression escapedPatternForString:theWord]]`. Otherwise, if a user types in "Car.*l", their input will be treated as a regular expression, and could cause a crash if it's an invalid one.