# NSPredicate to check if any word in string attribute matches search term in Swift

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nspredicate

I want to search a string attribute in Core Data for a search term using NSPredicate.  The string attribute may be one word or many e.g. `Ulysses` or `The Red Badge of Courage`.

I could use `contains` as in the following:

```
NSPredicate *pred= [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"title contains[cd] %@",str];
```

However, to guard against a match for the search term `rage`, for example, against `The Red Badge Of Courage` it would be safer to look for matches from the beginning of the word.

Is there a way to modify beginswith so that you can apply it to any word in the string, not just the whole string, ie some variation of:

```
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"title beginswith[cd] %@", str];
```

You can also search if the attribute value matches any word in the search term with:

```
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"SELF IN %@", str]
```

Basically, I want to do the opposite, check if the search string matches any word in the attribute in core data.

Thanks for any suggestions

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NSPredicate with a string matching beginning of words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11071455/nspredicate-with-a-string-matching-beginning-of-words)

Comment: There is only one answer in the linked to question but it solved my problem.  I don't know if there is a better way to do it, for example, without regex but this worked.  One thing I did was to move the creation of the regex string into a function.  That way I can dynamically create the predicate in the usual way without knowing the search term in advance

Comment: -(NSString*)makeRegexStringFrom:(NSString*) string {
    NSString *escapedSearchString = [NSRegularExpression escapedPatternForString: string];
    
    NSString *regexString  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(?w:).*\\b%@.*", escapedSearchString];
    
    return regexString;
}